# Ограничение ввода textField

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, javafx

```
TextFormatter<Integer> sevenFormat = new TextFormatter<>(c -> c
        .getControlNewText().length() > 4 ? null : c);
textFieldSizeFile.setTextFormatter(sevenFormat);

textFieldSizeFile.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<Integer>(change -> {
    if (!(change.getControlNewText().matches("[0-9]"))) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return change;
    }
}));
```

Как сделать так, чтобы было одновременно, и ограничение ввода символов (ничего кроме цифр), и их количество не более 4. По отдельности они работают, а вдвоем не хотят.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать один из них если подправить регекс

```
textFieldSizeFile.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<Integer>(change -> {
    if (!(change.getControlNewText().matches("[0-9]{1,4}"))) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return change;
    }
}));
```

Comment: Исправил.Все работает.Но одну букву все-таки можно иногда ввести

Answer (score 0):

```
 textFieldSizeFile.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<String>(change -> {
        if (!(change.getControlNewText().matches("[0-9]{0,4}"))) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return change;
        }
    }));
```

> Исправил.Все работает.Но единственное иногда почему-то одна буква вводится а потом не дает